# Execute JavaScript on successful Form Submission

Tags: sitecore-forms

I need to execute custom JavaScript code on a successful form submit. Are there any events that can be attached to?

Using Sitecore 9.0.2 with Forms Extensions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no built-in hooks or events, but by extending the RenderForm pipeline a JavaScript event can be emitted on success:

Config:

```
<pipelines>
   <forms.renderForm>        
    <processor type="MyProject.Pipelines.Forms.RenderForm.FormPostSuccessEvent, MyProject" resolve="true" 
               patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Pipelines.RenderForm.InitializeAjaxOptions, Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc']"/>
  </forms.renderForm>
</pipelines>
```

Processor:

```
public class FormPostSuccessEvent : MvcPipelineProcessor<RenderFormEventArgs>
{
    public override void Process(RenderFormEventArgs args)
    {
        var attributes = args.Attributes["data-ajax-success"] as string;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(attributes))
        {
            return;
        }

        args.Attributes["data-ajax-success"] = "document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('sc-forms-submit-success', {'detail': '" + args.FormHtmlId + "'}));" + attributes;
    }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener("sc-forms-submit-success", function(e) {
      var myForm = document.getElementById(e.detail);
      // do JS magic
});
```

Comment: I think your solution is awesome but it will always be data-ajax-success even when the form fails at server side.