# Forms and datalayer.push when successfully going to the next page or getting submitted

Tags: sitecore-forms, google-tag-manager

I need to make a `dataLayer.push({my_arguments_here})` whenever a form **successfully** goes to the next page/gets submitted. I know that some validation is happening on back-end, so I'm trying to find a JS code, which is checking if BE passed, before going to the next page. That's where I wanted to write my own code for `dataLayer.push()`. But I can't find any JS code which is doing that.

Any ideas where and/or how JS knows that BE passed validation successfully before going to the next form page? Or any other ideas on how to approach this?

I'm working on Sitecore 10.1.2

Comment: This may be a good starting point for you: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/24381/execute-javascript-on-successful-form-submission

Answer (score 0):

you can extend Sitecore Forms module to execute custom JavaScript code when the form, created in Sitecore is submitted by the users. This can work with multi-page forms with next buttons as well.

You need to write your `dataLayer.push({my_arguments_here})` under custom js to submit it before going to next page or form submission.

Extend a view model class representing submit button in Sitecore Forms.

```
using Sitecore;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Models.Fields;
 
namespace Sc.FormsCustomScripts.Models
{
    public class CustomScriptButtonViewModel : ButtonViewModel
    {
        public string FormSubmitScript { get; set; }
 
        protected override void InitItemProperties(Item item)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(item, nameof(item));
            base.InitItemProperties(item);
            FormSubmitScript = StringUtil.GetString((object)item.Fields["Form Submit Script"]);
        }
 
        protected override void UpdateItemFields(Item item)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(item, nameof(item));
            base.UpdateItemFields(item);
            item.Fields["Form Submit Script"]?.SetValue(FormSubmitScript, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Modify the view file responsible for rendering the button in Sitecore Forms `\Views\FormBuilder\FieldTemplates\Button.cshtml`

```
@using Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Constants
@model Sc.FormsCustomScripts.Models.CustomScriptButtonViewModel
 
@{
    var cssClass = Model.CssClass;
    if (Model.NavigationStep < 0)
    {
        var classes = Model.CssClass.Split(' ');
        if (!classes.Contains("cancel", StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.CssClass))
            {
                cssClass += " ";
            }
 
            cssClass += "cancel";
        }
    }
}
 
<input value="@Html.DisplayTextFor(t => Model.Title)" type="submit" class="@cssClass" name="@Html.Name(Model.ItemId)" data-sc-field-key="@Model.ConditionSettings.FieldKey" />
@Html.Hidden(AttributeNames.NavigationButtons, Model.ItemId)
@Html.Hidden(Model.ItemId, Model.NavigationStep)
 
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($) {
        var $inputEl = $("input[name='@Html.Name(Model.ItemId)']");
        var $formEl = $inputEl.closest('form');
        if ($inputEl.length == 0 || $formEl.length == 0) {
            return;
        }
        $inputEl.click(function () {
            $("input[type=submit]", $formEl).removeAttr("clicked");
            $(this).attr("clicked", "true");
        });
        @if (Sitecore.Context.Site.Name != "shell")
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.FormSubmitScript)) 
            { 
                <text>
                    $formEl.on("submit", function () {

                    //datalayer.push 
                      dataLayer.push({
                        'color': 'red',
                        'conversionValue': 50,
                        'event': 'customize'
                      });


                        if ($inputEl.attr('clicked')) {
                            @Html.Raw(Model.FormSubmitScript)
                        }
                    });
                </text>
            }
        }
    })(jQuery)
</script>
```

Reference: [Call Custom JavaScript on Sitecore Forms Submit](https://smartsitecore.com/en/call-custom-javascript-on-sitecore-forms-submit/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the tips, unfortunately it doesn't work as intended. I commented out the `Model.FormSubmitScript` for now, and added a `console.log()` after both `($formEl.on("submit", function () {` and `if ($inputEl.attr('clicked')) {`, and I can see console log only fires after the first code, even if the validation of required field failed, but it never reached the second code block at all

Comment: My bad on the last comment. I realized we already had a custom Button.cshtml so I had to change `input` to `button` in the script. I see my JS is being called now, but it fires up even if the form failed from back-end side, e.g. a field was required, I see the error messages on the form, but the JS still fires

Comment: You can ask another question with necessary details and mark this answer accepted as it resolved your initial query.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't resolve my initial query, as I need the JS to be called when form page moves **successfully** to the next page, while currently it is not. If backend validation fails (e.g., when a field is mandatory), it does not move to the next page and the JS is getting called, but it shouldn't.